# How to set 'MaxWidth' property for a 'Grid' control in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xaml, grid, xamarin.forms

XAML page in a *Xamarin Forms* app consists a Grid control. Grid control consists of Entry(TextBox) as child. *Width* of the Grid and Entry is set as '*'.

In *portrait* mode Entry needs to be expanded from leftmost to rightmost. It's working fine. But in **landscape** mode, **Width** of Entry needs to be **limited** to a value( similar to '**MaxWidth**' property). (i.e) Width should not exceed a set value.

Hope if we can set 'MaxWidth' property of parent Grid, then we can attain that. **How can we set 'MaxWidth' property for 'Grid' control in Xamarin Forms?**

Comment: Did you try to set Grid's WidthRequest to your desired value on the event of orientation change?